# Send the wrong url to the user's email by queuing to verify the email

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

Works well when I want to use Laravel's default email verifier But when I put the same method that sends the email in a queue, the url sent to the user is wrong

```
http://localhost/email/verify/65/36a5c019a9dc059333f38c329f3694d6ba646e36?expires=1614871373&signature=52f2f377d559a6bdd913b6fc210106b352ed1c60ff64cf1166d2b0ec562f086d
```

The above url is incorrect instead of localhost:8000 has only the localhost value

```
User Model 

 public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        sendEmailVerify::dispatch($this);
    }


Job 

 public function __construct(User $user)
    {
   
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    
    public function handle()
    {
       $this->user->notify(new \App\Notifications\VerifyEmail());
    }
```

Comment: what is the value of app_url in .env file?

Comment: @SachinKumar APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: check my answer then

Comment: @SachinKumar  This only happens when queuing

Comment: This will happen for all the things which are running standalone like jobs, queues email. One quick solution is to set APP_URL=http://localhost:8000 but in that case, you have to simentensously run the server using php artisan serve command,

Comment: @SachinKumar  I used your solution but it still emails the same url

Comment: you have to restart the artisan serve command and also clear the cache by using php artisan optimize:clear command after changing the value in .env file

Comment: @SachinKumar I know he still has the same problem

Comment: IDK what is going to happen on your system. It is the right way to perform the system with new configuration. I hope you restart queue worker

Answer (score 2):

If you are using artisan queue:work, you also have to restart the worker after changing the app URL in the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

change value of APP_URL to

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

then run php artisan config:clear or php artisan config:cache

or if you are using php artisan serve just restart it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue exists because the queue job picks the env configuration value and in your case, the APP_URL is set to http://localhost/ I guess.

So change the APP_URL to the path of the local server in .env file like

> APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel

where laravel is my folder name where the project is running.